# Creating dynamically sized MPI file views

Tags: io, mpi

I would like to write out a binary file using collective MPI I/O.    My plan is to create an MPI derived type analogous to

```
struct soln_dynamic_t
{
    int int_data[2];
    double *u;   /* Length constant for all instances of this struct */
};
```

Each processor then creates a view based on the derived type, and writes into the view.

I have  this all working for the case  in which `*u` is replaced with `u[10]` (see complete code below), but ultimately, I'd like to have a dynamic length array for `u`.  (In case it matters, the length will be fixed for all instances of `soln_dynamic_t` for any run, but not known at compile time.)

What is the best way to handle this?

I have read several posts on why I can't use `soln_dynamic_t` 
directly as an MPI structure.  The problem is that processors are not guaranteed to have the same offset between `u[0]` and `int_data[0]`.  (Is that right?)

On the other hand, the structure

```
struct soln_static_t
{
    int int_data[2];
    double u[10];     /* fixed at compile time */
};
```

works because the offsets are guaranteed to be the same across processors.

I've considered several approaches :

- Create the view based on manually defined offsets, etc, rather than using a derived type.
- Base the MPI structure on another MPI type, i.e. an contiguous type for ``*u` (is that allowed?)

I am guessing there must be a standard way to do this. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Several other posts on this issue have been helpful, although they mostly deal with communication and not file I/O.

Here is the complete code::

```
#include <mpi.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int int_data[2];
    double u[10];  /* Make this a dynamic length (but fixed) */
} soln_static_t;


void build_soln_type(int n, int* int_data, double *u, MPI_Datatype *soln_t)
{
    int block_lengths[2] = {2,n};
    MPI_Datatype typelist[2] = {MPI_INT, MPI_DOUBLE};

    MPI_Aint disp[2], start_address, address;    
    MPI_Address(int_data,&start_address);
    MPI_Address(u,&address);
    disp[0] = 0;
    disp[1] = address-start_address;

    MPI_Datatype tmp_type;
    MPI_Type_create_struct(2,block_lengths,disp,typelist,&tmp_type);

    MPI_Aint extent;
    extent = block_lengths[0]*sizeof(int) + block_lengths[1]*sizeof(double);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(tmp_type, 0, extent, soln_t);
    MPI_Type_commit(soln_t);
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MPI_File   file;
    int globalsize, localsize, starts, order;

    MPI_Datatype localarray, soln_t;
    int rank, nprocs, nsize = 10;  /* must match size in struct above */

    /* --- Initialize MPI */
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);

    /* --- Set up data to write out */
    soln_static_t data;
    data.int_data[0] = nsize;
    data.int_data[1] = rank;
    data.u[0] = 3.14159;  /* To check that data is written as expected */
    build_soln_type(nsize, data.int_data, data.u, &soln_t);

    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "bin.out", 
                  MPI_MODE_CREATE|MPI_MODE_WRONLY,
                  MPI_INFO_NULL, &file);

    /* --- Create file view for this processor */
    globalsize = nprocs;  
    localsize = 1;
    starts = rank;
    order = MPI_ORDER_C;

    MPI_Type_create_subarray(1, &globalsize, &localsize, &starts, order, 
                             soln_t, &localarray);
    MPI_Type_commit(&localarray);

    MPI_File_set_view(file, 0, soln_t, localarray, 
                           "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);

    /* --- Write data into view */
    MPI_File_write_all(file, data.int_data, 1, soln_t, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

    /* --- Clean up */
    MPI_File_close(&file);

    MPI_Type_free(&localarray);
    MPI_Type_free(&soln_t);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the size of the `u` array of the `soln_dynamic_t` type is known at runtime and will not change after that, I'd rather suggest an other approach.

Basically, you store all the data contiguous in memory :

```
typedef struct
{
    int int_data[2];
    double u[];  /* Make this a dynamic length (but fixed) */
} soln_dynamic_t;
```

Then you have to manually allocate this struct

```
soln_dynamic_t * alloc_soln(int nsize, int count) {
    return (soln_dynamic_t *)calloc(offsetof(soln_dynamic_t, u)+nsize*sizeof(double), count);
}
```

Note you cannot directly access an array of `soln_dynamic_t` because the size is unknown at compile time. Instead, you have to manually calculate the pointers.

```
soln_dynamic_t *p = alloc_soln(10, 2);
p[0].int_data[0] = 1;  // OK
p[0].u[0] = 2;         // OK
p[1].int_data[0] = 3;  // KO ! since sizeof(soln_dynamic_t) is unknown at compile time.
```

Here is the full rewritten version of your program

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int int_data[2];
    double u[];  /* Make this a dynamic length (but fixed) */
} soln_dynamic_t;


void build_soln_type(int n, MPI_Datatype *soln_t)
{
    int block_lengths[2] = {2,n};
    MPI_Datatype typelist[2] = {MPI_INT, MPI_DOUBLE};
    MPI_Aint disp[2];

    disp[0] = offsetof(soln_dynamic_t, int_data);
    disp[1] = offsetof(soln_dynamic_t, u);

    MPI_Datatype tmp_type;
    MPI_Type_create_struct(2,block_lengths,disp,typelist,&tmp_type);

    MPI_Aint extent;
    extent = offsetof(soln_dynamic_t, u) + block_lengths[1]*sizeof(double);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(tmp_type, 0, extent, soln_t);
    MPI_Type_free(&tmp_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(soln_t);
}

soln_dynamic_t * alloc_soln(int nsize, int count) {
    return (soln_dynamic_t *)calloc(offsetof(soln_dynamic_t, u) + nsize*sizeof(double), count);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MPI_File   file;
    int globalsize, localsize, starts, order;

    MPI_Datatype localarray, soln_t;
    int rank, nprocs, nsize = 10;  /* must match size in struct above */

    /* --- Initialize MPI */
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);

    /* --- Set up data to write out */
    soln_dynamic_t *data = alloc_soln(nsize,1);
    data->int_data[0] = nsize;
    data->int_data[1] = rank;
    data->u[0] = 3.14159;  /* To check that data is written as expected */
    build_soln_type(nsize, &soln_t);

    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "bin2.out", 
                  MPI_MODE_CREATE|MPI_MODE_WRONLY,
                  MPI_INFO_NULL, &file);

    /* --- Create file view for this processor */
    globalsize = nprocs;  
    localsize = 1;
    starts = rank;
    order = MPI_ORDER_C;

    MPI_Type_create_subarray(1, &globalsize, &localsize, &starts, order, 
                             soln_t, &localarray);
    MPI_Type_commit(&localarray);

    MPI_File_set_view(file, 0, soln_t, localarray, 
                           "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);

    /* --- Write data into view */
    MPI_File_write_all(file, data, 1, soln_t, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

    /* --- Clean up */
    MPI_File_close(&file);

    MPI_Type_free(&localarray);
    MPI_Type_free(&soln_t);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow - thanks!   This looks like a really cool solution, and does exactly what I want.  If I understand it correctly, you are faking out the usual mechanism by which structures are allocated and dynamically creating memory and casting it as a `soln_dynamic_t` pointer.   You say that the fields of the struct cannot be accessed directly, but in fact you do access them just as if they were a usual structure (`data->int_data[0] = 3', etc).

Comment: I also noticed that you only reference the type `soln_dynamic_t` when building the derived type (instead of taking addresses of fields of an actual instance of the struct)  and instead just use `offsetof`.  Is the general way to build types, even for more usual structs?

Comment: @Donna what I said i you can access `data->int_data[0]` which is equivalent to `data[0].int_data[0]` but I think accessing `data[1].int_data[0]` will generate **incorrect** code.

Comment: @Donna using the `offsetof()` macro does not require you to allocate the structure, does not require you to use `MPI_Get_address()` nor pointer arithmetic (btw, you should really use `MPI_Aint_diff()` instead of the `-` operator). As a matter of style, I find it more elegant (and compact) than handling addresses.

Comment: @Giles Gouaillardet  If I understand what you are saying, then, would it be correct to access fields in the pointer `soln_dynamic_t *ptr = (soln_dynamic_t*) data[1]`, i.e. `ptr->int_data[0]`?

Comment: No, you would need to do something like `soln_dynamic_t *ptr = (sol_dynamic_t *)((char *)data + offsetof(soln_dynamic_t, u) + nsize*sizeof(double))` and then `ptr->int_data[0]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167131/discussion-between-donna-and-gilles-gouaillardet).