# Define a MPI_type_struct with a dynamic array inside

Tags: mpi

I'm trying to create an hybrid code MPI+MPI shared memory.
I'm able to create a new datatype with a struct with "fixed" dimension like this:

```
struct st_Data
{
    int nWRank;
    int nSRank;
    char cName[160];
    int nData;
};
```

usign this MPI code:

```
MPI_Aint offsets[] = {(MPI_Aint)offsetof(struct st_Data, nWRank), (MPI_Aint)offsetof(struct st_Data, nSRank), (MPI_Aint)offsetof(struct st_Data, cName), (MPI_Aint)offsetof(struct st_Data, nData)};
MPI_Datatype types[] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_CHAR, MPI_INT};  
int blockcounts[] = {1, 1, 160, 1};
MPI_Datatype myMPI_Data;
MPI_Type_struct(4, blockcounts, offsets, types, &myMPI_Data);
MPI_Type_commit(&myMPI_Data);
```

and it works prefectly (I tryed with MPI_Scatterv and MPI_Gatherv).

I would like to modify the struct like this:

```
struct st_Data
{
    int nWRank;
    int nSRank;
    char cName[160];
    int *nData;
};
```

and define the dimension of the array *nData with malloc (I would like to read the dimension from ready a file data, for example).

Is it possible? If yes, have you any suggestions for modifying the MPI_Datatype definition?

Comment: Short answer: You cannot. Check for example this https://stackoverflow.com/q/2258759/7141543

Comment: An other approach is outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370671/creating-dynamically-sized-mpi-file-views/49374582#49374582, not sure this is a fit here though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer